# Can you add leading zero's to an inner join

Tags: sql-server-2012

Got a general question - can you add leading zero's to an inner join in the FROM clause?

I am trying to join two tables, the 1st column [EmployeeNum (float,null)] needs 3 leading zero's in order to join with the other column [SalesID (varchar(8)].

ie...

SELECT...
FROM database.table1 ta1 
INNER JOIN database.table2 t2 on ta1.*000*EmployeeNum = ta2.SalesID

is it even possible?

Comment: `SELECT * 
FROM database.table1 ta1 
INNER JOIN database.table2 t2 on '000' + ta1.EmployeeNum = ta2.SalesID`

Comment: juergen d....that was too easy!...classic example, for me, of not seeing the forest for the trees. thanks very much